# Parse dates with timezone

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

This works correctly and return "2020-02-01 00:00:01.132 UTC". But if the time zone is part of parse_datetime function, it does not work.

Works:

```
select parse_datetime('2020-02-01 00:00:01.132000' ,'yyyy-MM-dd'' ''HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS');
```

Does not work:

```
select parse_datetime('2020-02-01 00:00:01.132000+5:30' ,'yyyy-MM-dd'' ''HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS''Z');
```

The error says malformed at "+5:30". How do I parse dates with timezone in athena?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select parse_datetime('2020-02-01 00:00:01.132000+05:30' ,'yyyy-MM-dd'' ''HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ');
```

Comment: Is the only difference adding a leading zero to the timezone offset?